# Java novice error Android Programming sendMessage method

Tags: java, android, eclipse

so I started some Android programming with Java 7. I have Eclipse Juno (I think that's 4.2).

The problem is that it gives me an error "Multiple markers at this line
    - Syntax error on token ")", ; 
     expected
    - Syntax error on token ")", ; 
     expected

On the line with the sendMessage method. Here is the code:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {


int counter;
Button login; 
EditText username, password;
String success;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    counter = 0;

    username = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.getEmail);
    password = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.getPassword);        

    login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {       
        public void onClick (View v) {
            if(username.getText().toString().equals("admin") && password.getText().toString().equals("admin")){
                success = "Successful";
                counter = 0;
                public void sendMessage (View view){
                    Intent intent = new Intent("com.example.linked1n.SCREENAFTLOG");
                    startActivity(intent);
                };
            } else {
                    counter++;
                    login.setText("Unsuccessful. Try again. " + 3-counter + " tries left.");
            }   
        }   
    });



}
```

I haven't found a solution anywhere and I did exactly as the tutorial told me. I tried to clean the project thrice and restart eclipse/computer nothing worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your calling method inside onclick is wrong so try below way :-

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    counter = 0;

    username = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.getEmail);
    password = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.getPassword);        

    login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {       
        public void onClick (View v) {
            if(username.getText().toString().equals("admin") && password.getText().toString().equals("admin")){
                success = "Successful";
                counter = 0;
               sendMessage(v);
            } else {
                    counter++;
                    login.setText("Unsuccessful. Try again. " + 3-counter + " tries left.");
            }   
        }   
    });

 public void sendMessage (View view){
                        Intent intent = new Intent("com.example.linked1n.SCREENAFTLOG");
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 problems in your code :

1. You are not calling the function, just defining it, that too inside the `onClick` method, which you should not do.This problem can be resolved by calling the method inside the `onClick` and defining it outside the `onClickListener`.
2. You shouldn't terminate your `sendMessage` method declaration with a semi colon after the ending curly brace.This problem can be resolved by removing the semicolon from there.

So your code finally looks as below :

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity { 


int counter;
Button login; 
EditText username, password;
String success;


@Override 
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    counter = 0;

    username = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.getEmail);
    password = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.getPassword);        

    login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {        
        public void onClick (View v) { 
            if(username.getText().toString().equals("admin") && password.getText().toString().equals("admin")){ 
                success = "Successful"; 
                counter = 0; 
                sendMessage(v);//Method sendMesaage is called inside onClick

            } else { 
                    counter++; 
                    login.setText("Unsuccessful. Try again. " + 3-counter + " tries left."); 
            }    
        }    
    }); 
     //Definition of method sendMessage
     public void sendMessage (View view){ 
                    Intent intent = new Intent("com.example.linked1n.SCREENAFTLOG"); 
                    startActivity(intent); 
                }//Removed semicolon from the method sendMessage
}
```